# Why message property SPRING_AUTO_DECOMPRESS has to be present, after DelegatingDecompressingPostProcessor detects correct encoding

Tags: spring-amqp

Currently i use

`rabbitTemplate.addAfterReceivePostProcessors(new DelegatingDecompressingPostProcessor());`

and

`UserRprt userRprt=(UserRprt) rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(RESPONSE_QUEUE, 10000);`

The received message has a 'gzip' as encoding property and the DelegatingDecompressingPostProcessor already delegates the message to the GUnzipPostProcessor. **Why i have to add the message property SPRING_AUTO_DECOMPRESS to decompress the content by the GUnzipPostProcessor?**  If i not the set this property with additional message post processor, GUnzipPostProcessor will not decompress the message.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a GitHub issue for this; it should set the `alwaysDecompress` option to true on the delegates. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues

In the meantime, you can `removeDecompressor("gzip")` and add it back, with the `alwaysDecompress` property set to true. Same for the other supported encodings.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1320